# Want to configure shared tomcat realm with different datasources

Tags: tomcat, single-sign-on, tomcat5.5

I have two sets of web applications that all run on the same Tomcat 5.5 server.

I have one common Realm defined in `server.xml`:

```
<!-- Define the top level container in our container hierarchy -->
<Engine defaultHost="localhost" name="Catalina">

    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />

    <Realm
        className="com.key.portal.common.realm.PortalDataSourceRealm"
        debug="0"
        dataSourceName="jdbc/usa"
        userTable="user_info"
        userNameCol="username"
        userIdCol="username"
        userCredCol="password"
        userInactiveCol="inactive"
        userRoleTable="user_role"
        roleNameCol="role" />
```

My "usa" applications both want to share a SingleSignOn with this datasource, and my "canada" applications to use singlesignon, but with a different datasource. (e.g.   `jdbc/canada`)

Is there a way I can split this top level Engine container into two divisions, or configure the applications to override the `dataSourceName`?  The tomcat docs say I can have exactly one "Engine" section defined.

But both sets of web applications want to use a different datasource to connect to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the `Realm` inside a `Host` (or even inside a `Context`) element. If your *usa* and *canada* applications run in different `Host`s it could be a solution.

If they are inside the same `Host` you have to put a `Realm` tag inside every `Context` of the *usa* applications and let the *canada* apps use the default Realm (which is nested in the `Engine` tag) or vice versa.

From the documentation, [Realm Configuration HOW-TO, Configuring a Realm](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/realm-howto.html#Configuring_a_Realm):

> The  element can be nested inside any one of of the following
>   Container elements. The location of the Realm element has a direct
>   impact on the "scope" of that Realm (i.e. which web applications will
>   share the same authentication information):
>
> [...]
>
> - Inside a  element - This Realm will be shared across ALL web applications for THIS virtual host, UNLESS it is overridden by a Realm
>     element nested inside a subordinate  element.
> - Inside a  element - This Realm will be used ONLY for THIS web application.

Here is a similar question with an example in the answers: [how can I restrict users to access ONLY their own manager?](https://serverfault.com/questions/315641/tomcat6-how-can-i-restrict-users-to-acces-only-their-own-manager)